# extending sales/quote class

Tags: magento-1.9, module, overrides, core

I want to to extend the core model class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` located in `Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` I created this directory `local/Lemerge/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php`

And I created the config.xml file in `local/Lemerge/Sales/etc` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Lemerge_Sales>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Lemerge_Sales>
</modules>
<global>
   <models>
    <sales>
      <rewrite>
        <quote_item>Lemerge_Sales_Model_Quote_Item</quote_item>
      </rewrite>
    </sales>
   </models>
</global>
</config>
```

In `app/etc/modules` I created Lemerge_Sales.xml I don't know even if it necessary

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>  
<modules>  
    <Lemerge_Sales>  
        <active>true</active>  
        <codepool>local</codepool>  
    </Lemerge_Sales>  
</modules>  
</config>
```

Then I override the `setProudct()` in Item.php

```
<?php
class Lemerge_Sales_Model_Quote_Item extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
{
   public function setProduct($product)
   {
     //code 
   }
}
```

But it does not work magento is using the core file instead of the overrided file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing the following in your config.xml

```
         <lemerge_sales>
            <class>Lemerge_Sales_Model</class>
        </lemerge_sales>
```

correct way:

```
<global>
   <models>
   <lemerge_sales>
        <class>Lemerge_Sales_Model</class>
    </lemerge_sales>
    <sales>
      <rewrite>
        <quote_item>Lemerge_Sales_Model_Quote_Item</quote_item>
      </rewrite>
    </sales>
   </models>
</global>
```

Also you are misspelling the coodPool in Lemerge_Sales.xml

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

correct way:

```
<config>  
  <modules>  
   <Lemerge_Sales>  
     <active>true</active>  
     <codePool>local</codePool>  
   </Lemerge_Sales>  
  </modules>  
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks to tell me the correct way I tried it, but didn't work then I saw the config I figured that I wrote codepool instead of codePool. but also it work without    <class>Lemerge_Sales_Model</class> could you please write what will happen when if I wrote it or not ?

Comment: You wont be able to instatiate any models in your extention. Thus mage::getModel('lemerge_sales') would not work

Comment: You should accept this answer. Not configuring the model is more critical than misspelling `codePool`, IMO.

Comment: If this answer isn't working for you, then you need to delete the var/cache directory manually. That will completely refresh your system and this should begin working for you.

Comment: @laketuna I will accept it, I will edit the answer to write about the misspelling codePool so people can know the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

I found a silly mistake that cost me more than 12 hours.

I wrote `codepool` instead of `codePool`

Editing Lemerge_Sales.xml to the code below solved the problem

```
<config>  
  <modules>  
    <Lemerge_Sales>  
       <active>true</active>  
       <codePool>local</codePool>  
    </Lemerge_Sales>  
  </modules>  
</config>
```

Comment: Lol, easy to miss, been there, especially when case in folder path is wrong.

Comment: I can't count the number of times I did this mistake. You would think I would learn after the first 15 times, but NO.  I can hardly wait for Magento 2 to get rid of the code pools.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not define model in config.xml try this code

```
  <models>
     <sales>
         <class>Lemerge_Sales_Model</class>
     </sales>
 </models>
```

Change in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Lemerge_Sales>
         <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Lemerge_Sales>
</modules>
<global>
   <models>
     <sales>
         <class>Lemerge_Sales_Model</class>
     </sales>
    <sales>
       <rewrite>
         <quote_item>Lemerge_Sales_Model_Quote_Item</quote_item>
       </rewrite>
    </sales>
</models>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: why post an identical answer that was done 5 hours ago?

Comment: also this is wrong, as the namespace placed in the model is not SALES, but lemerge_sales.